# Cosa significa "grifagno" riferito a un vascello secentesco?

Tags: word-meaning

Nel romanzo *Artemisia*, di Anna Banti, ho letto:

> Ma le più volte, al calar del sole, Artemisia se ne sta in altana a pigliare il fresco senza che nessuno la veda. Guarda il mare cresputo e irrequieto, i vascelli che giostrano, **grifagni** come mostri, gonfi di vento, ispidi di alberature e di corde.

Più avanti nel libro, questi "grifagni" riferiti ai vascelli appaiono di nuovo:

> Gli operai dei vascelli in riparazione, intorno alle gran caldaie di pece fumante, gli uomini di quelli in partenza, i barcaioli da trasporto, i pescatori che facevan colazione a bordo, lanciavano domande, auguri, saluti. Solo dai vascelli da guerra, due galere francesi e un galeone spagnolo, non partì voce, pur colmi di soldati e galeoti com'erano. La *Jonathan* ci girò intorno, radendo con certa bravura guardigna gli ornati **grifagni**, le formidabili macchine.

In questo brano, la *Jonathan* è la nave che trasporta la pittrice Artemisia Gentileschi in Inghilterra.

Ho cercato "grifagno" in alcuni dizionari e ho trovato che si tratta di un aggettivo che può riferirsi a un uccello rapace o agli occhi di una persona che assomigliano a quelli di un uccello rapace. Non capisco però cosa intenda dire l'autrice qualificando i vascelli come "grifagni". Si riferisce forse agli ornamenti dei vascelli?

Answer (score 2):

*Grifagno* significa "torvo, minaccioso, sinistro". Tutta la prima descrizione mi sembra caratterizzata da un senso di cupezza: il mare inquieto, i vascelli che sembrano mostri minacciosi e ispidi...
Nel secondo caso, *grifagni* dovrebbe essere un sostantivo, e forse si riferisce, appunto, a quegli ornamenti che si mettevano sulle navi per spaventare un eventuale nemico durante le battaglie o il mare stesso (il "nemico" per eccellenza). Questi ornamenti, che dunque non servivano a rendere più belle le navi, erano di solito figure mitologiche o animali predatori.